# Nancy fx how to use in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, web-services, nancy

Here I have a simple WinForm app which has a NancyFx service all working fine: I use a Person object which implements the IPerson interface. The nancyModule has a ctor with a parameter of IPerson and in the post route of the nancyModule I use the this.Bind(); If I want to display the person on the form how do I do it?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.ModelBinding;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IDisposable dispose;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string uri = "http://localhost:8080/";
           dispose = WebApp.Start<Startup1>(uri);
        }
    }

    public interface IPerson
    {
        String Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Person : IPerson
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class nancyModule : NancyModule
    {
        public nancyModule(IPerson person)
        {
            Post["/data"] = _ =>
            {
                person = this.Bind<Person>();
                //HOW DO I DISPLAY THE person  ON THE FORM UI
               return HttpStatusCode.OK;
           };
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the person data on the form then you need to call your REST API from your Win Forms application. Grab the response and output the results. Simply put, this is how you can achieve this.

> I haven't used `async` and `await` keywords which ideally you would but
>   for brevity I have omitted this.

Firstly, I removed the dependency of `IPerson` from your module as this isn't a dependency as such but an output from your `POST`. With that minor adjustment, it looks like this:

**If you still feel strongly about `IPerson` being a dependency then simply leave it and the code will still work as expected.**

```
public class PersonModule : NancyModule
{
    public PersonModule()
    {
        this.Post["/data"] = args => this.AddPerson();
    }

    private Negotiator AddPerson()
    {
        var person = this.Bind<Person>();

        return this.Negotiate
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created)
            .WithContentType("application/json")
            .WithModel(person);
    }
}
```

Now from your Win Forms application simply call the API via the `HttpClient`, like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var person = new Person { Name = "Foo Bar" };
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var response = client.PostAsync(
        "http://localhost:8080/data",
        new StringContent(serializer.Serialize(person), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    TextBox1.Text = result.Forename;
}
```

> Purest's out there will mention 3rd party libraries such as `Json.NET`
>   and `Service Stack` which allows for easier `serialization` and
>   `deserialization`  but again for simplicity in this example I am using
>   `out of the box features`.

Comment: Yes that would seem to be the way forward. My thoughts were muddled on the this question I guess the essence of what I was trying to get at was can I inject Nancy itself as an dependency into a form but there is no way to do that. Thank mate.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.

Comment: This is a very good example. Could you kindly point me to where I could learn more about it? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance you can look here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy and here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation. However, it looks like Nancy is no longer maintained. I would use a different framework.